# Simple JavaScript Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript

I have written the below mentioned javascript and have called on the button click event but somehow it doesn't work, please someone help.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML
    if(x==1)
    {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" id="txt1"/><br/>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" value="submit" onclick="f1()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should not be  `.innerHTML`, but `.value`.

Comment: Why? It's a function, it doesn't matter if it's before or after the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to grab `innerHTML` from an input field when you should be grabbing the `value` otherwise it'll always be `undefined`:

Change:

```
var x = document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML;
```

to:

```
var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
```

JSFiddle Example

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/dNWNP/1/**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `value` instead of `innerHTML`:

```
var x=document.getElementById("txt1").value;
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjX3h/).

Comment: Not my downvote but your no. 3 makes no difference since it's not strict equality `(("1"==1) === ("1"=="1"))` // true. Otherwise use strict equality

Comment: The semi-colon makes no practical difference either.